# Trouble with libstatgrab

Tags: c++, c, linker, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

Having trouble using libstatgrab -- I receive the following error at compile time:

`"libstatgrabTest.cpp:16: undefined reference to sg_get_process_stats"`

I'm guessing it is because I need to include it's .so files at the linking state -- although I'm not sure. As you can see below, I am currently including the `statgrab.h` header file. I performed `configured && make && make install` for the library.

If I search for libstatgrab*, I come across the following:

```
./usr/local/lib/libstatgrab.so.6.2.3
./usr/local/lib/libstatgrab.la
./usr/local/lib/libstatgrab.so.6
./usr/local/lib/libstatgrab.a
./usr/local/lib/libstatgrab.so.6.2.2
./usr/local/lib/libstatgrab.so
./usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libstatgrab.pc
```

Another search for statgrab* returns the following (relevant items only):

```
./usr/local/bin/statgrab
./usr/local/include/statgrab_deprecated.h
./usr/local/include/statgrab.h
```

At compilation, I run: `g++ -g -c libstatgrabTest.cpp`

At linking, I run: `g++ -L/usr/local/lib libstatgrab.o -o libstatgrabTest`

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The code within `libstagrabTest.cpp` is shown below:

```
// external libraries
#include <statgrab.h> // libstatgrab (http://www.i-scream.org/libstatgrab/)

// namespace
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  // try to initalize libstatgrab

  int * entries;
  sg_process_stats * systemStats = sg_get_process_stats(entries);

  // return
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib libstatgrab.o -o libstatgrabTest
```

should be (tested with your code snipper on Ubuntu Natty):

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o libstatgrabTest -lstatgrab
```

or, to link statically:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o libstatgrabTest /usr/lib/libstatgrab.a
```

Tested both on my box, with your exact source.

Comment: The changes between "libstatgrab" and "statgrab" confused me -- I had previously also included -llibstatgrab and it was giving me the same error... Thanks a bunch

Comment: Would linking statically include the library within the executable? I.E, how can I ensure that if I move (only) the executable to a second system, that I will not need to install libstatgrab? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Link it statically, indeed. My resulting executable depended on no 'external' libs (outside linux and libc)